# Laravel, sort result on field from relation table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a list with gamers and another table with game stats.

My list code is:

```
$gamers = Gamer::with(['lastGameStat' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('total_points', 'DESC');
}])->paginate(20);
```

relation:

```
public function lastGameStat() {
        return $this->hasOne(GameStat::class, 'gamer_id', 'id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
```

in relation table I have field: `total_points` and with this code I thought it's possible to sort list of gamers by `total_points` `$query->orderBy('total_points', 'DESC');`

It doesn't work, can somebody give me an advice here how can I sort the result on a field from relation table?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll need either another relation or custom scopes to fetch various game stats of a gamer.

## Second relation

**Gamer.php** (your model)

```
class Gamer
{
    public function bestGameStat()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(GameStat::class)
            ->orderBy('total_points', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

## Custom scopes

**Gamer.php**

```
class Gamer
{
    public function gameStat()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(GameStat::class);
    }
}
```

**GameStat.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class GameStat
{
    public function scopeBest(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('total_points', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

**In your controller:**

```
$gamersWithTheirLatestGameStatistic = Gamer::with(['gameStat' => function($query) {
    $query->latest();
}])->paginate(20);

$gamersWithTheirBestGameStatistic = Gamer::with(['gameStat' => function($query) {
    $query->best();
}])->paginate(20);
```

Be aware as this is untested code and might not work.